# PDE characteristics.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have solved the following equation using characteristics:
$$u_{xx}+2u_{xy}-3u_{yy}=0$$
and obtained the characteristics:
$$\xi=x+y$$
$$\eta=x-\frac{1}{3}y$$
I have determined the general solution to be of the form:
$$u(x,y)=F(x+y)+G(x-\frac{1}{3}y)$$
Given the conditions:
$$u(x=0,y)=y, u_x(x=0,y)=y$$
I am having a hard time finding the particular solution. Applying the first condition I obtained:
$$F(y)+G(-\frac{1}{3}y)=y$$
I am not quite sure how to correctly differentiate $u(x,y)$ wrt $x$ and also how to combine both conditions to yield the particular solution.
I'd be thankful for some guidance.

Comment: Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula

Answer (score 1):

Please use the general solution of the form $u(x,y)=F(x+y)+G(y-3x)$ instead for convenience.

$u(0,y)=y$ :

$F(y)+G(y)=y$

$u_x(0,y)=y$ :

$F'(y)-3G'(y)=y$

$F(y)-3G(y)=\dfrac{y^2}{2}+c$

$\therefore F(y)=\dfrac{y^2+6y+2c}{8},G(y)=\dfrac{y-y^2-2c}{8}$

$\therefore u(x,y)=\dfrac{(x+y)^2+6(x+y)+y-3x-(y-3x)^2}{8}$